# How to give the DKGRAY_BRUSH to the area of the main window?

Tags: c++, winapi

I give the background main window color by registering the window class with the hbrBackground property like this :

```
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(DKGRAY_BRUSH);
```

and then :

```
RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
```

The result window is white. I have the darkgray color when I minimize/maximize the window.
How can I obtain the darkgray background immediately ?

Thank you !

EDIT : The callback function :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hgGroupBox1;
    static HWND hsFileSize;
    static HWND hsFileName;
    static HWND hsStatic1;
    static HWND hsStatic2;
    static HWND hsStatic3;
    static HWND hsStatic4;
    static HWND hsFileID;
    static HWND hlbTagV2Frames;

    static HWND hStatus;

    static HBRUSH hbrBkgnd;

    int hauteur, largeur;
    std::wstringstream lbFrames;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

        hsStatic1 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", L"Fichier :", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 5, 5, 60, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_STATIC1, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
        hsFileName = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 65, 5, 800, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_STATICFILENAME, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
        hgGroupBox1 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", L"TagV2", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX, 5, 30, 420, hauteur - 100, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_GROUPEBOX1, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
        hsStatic2 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", L"Taille :", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 15, 50, 100, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_STATIC2, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
        hsFileSize = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 15, 75, 100, 20, hWnd, (HMENU) ID_STATICFILESIZE, (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
        hsStatic3 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", L"Entête :", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 15, 100, 100, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_STATIC3, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
        hsFileID = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 15, 125, 200, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_STATICENTETEID, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
        hsStatic4 = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", L"Attributs du tagV2 :", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 15, 150, 150, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_GROUPEBOX1, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);
        hlbTagV2Frames = CreateWindow(L"LISTBOX", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | LBS_NOTIFY, 15, 175, 400, 200, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_LISTBOXFRAMES, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), nullptr);

        ShowWindow(hsStatic1, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(hgGroupBox1, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(hsStatic2, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(hsFileSize, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(hsStatic3, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(hsFileID, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(hStatus, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(hsStatic4, SW_SHOW);
        ShowWindow(hlbTagV2Frames, SW_SHOW);

        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Analyse les sélections de menu :
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_FICHIER_OUVRIR:
               //Here comes the file treatement code.

                }
                break;
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Ajoutez ici le code de dessin qui utilise hdc...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        {
            HDC hdcStatic = (HDC)wParam;
            SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            SetBkColor(hdcStatic, DKGRAY_BRUSH);
            hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(DKGRAY_BRUSH);
            return (INT_PTR)hbrBkgnd;
        }
        }
    case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
        {
            HDC hdcButton = (HDC)wParam;
            SetTextColor(hdcButton, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            SetBkColor(hdcButton, DKGRAY_BRUSH);
        }
        hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(DKGRAY_BRUSH);
        return (INT_PTR)hbrBkgnd;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Are you calling [UpdateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatewindow) after the window has been created?

Comment: Yes. ShowWindow then UpdateWindow.

Comment: That's the correct usage, you must have a problem somewhere else in your code. Maybe you are painting the window in `WM_PAINT`, etc.

Comment: Or not passing `WM_ERASEBKGND` through to `DefWindowProc`.

Comment: It seems what prevents the area of the main window from redrawing, can you provide your callback function?

Comment: I don't do anything in the `WM_PAINT` message but preparing a possible drawing I maybe don't need : `PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
           
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);` I don't manipulate `WM_ERASEBKGND` in anyway. Should I do ?

Comment: You have a `case WM_ERASEBKGND` which breaks out of the switch, and means it **doesn't** get passed through to `DefWindowProc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [WM_ERASEBKGND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-erasebkgnd) : Sent when the window background must be erased (for example, when a window is resized). The message is sent to
>   prepare an invalidated portion of a window for painting.

**The simplest solution：** delete `WM_ERASEBKGND` message or add `return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam)` in the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message if you do not want delete `WM_ERASEBKGND`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WM_PAINT to fill the main window with the Brush using FillRect in your windows procedure. That should accomplish what you want.

```
case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION + 1));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    } return 0;
```

See the FillRect function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-fillrect